# Can I get a full site map in html agility pack?

Tags: html-parsing, html-agility-pack, sitemap

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to use HTML Agility pack](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/846994/how-to-use-html-agility-pack)

I haven't yet downloaded Html Agility Pack, so I am wondering if I can easily make it parse a website (that may contain PHP) and make me a site map of html files in memory. Is Html Agility Pack designed to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Html Agility Pack is a framework for working with html documents object model. This won't help you to build sitemap directly.

You may use it in your own logic, but it will only cover navigation inside the DOM.

A side note: HAP is not a Microsoft product, but a community open source project.